# ADFS returning claim from extended attribute

Tags: attributes, schema, adfs

I have extended my Active directory by adding new custom attribute to the schema, let say TwitterAccount.

I need to return this attribute as a claim to web application that call ADFS for logon.

I tried to edit rule and add mapping by typing the name of LDAP attribute and a outgoing claim, but by doing that make ADFS page throws an error (GUID).

So, how can I return this extended attribute as a claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, in some ways, going to be dependent on how you configured your claims.

I've done the same kind of schema extension and created a custom claims rule that looks like this:

```
c:[Type =="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://testdomain.local/claims/customSchemaId"), query = ";customSchemaId;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

Which drops the extended attribute into the claim.

Comment: Hi Sam,
Adding this, and currently ask my colleague to test it out.

Comment: Adding this, does extend the claim rules, but not in LDAP attribute. 

If I type extend LDAP attribute name inside rule (have to type since it not in LDAP attribute drop downlist) and match it with Claim type dropdown. ADFS will throw an error in GUID when user tried to logon.

Is there something missing? How I put extended attribute in LDAP dropdown list?

Comment: Hi Sam,

It works... just my silly mistakes before this in making up Claim identifier. Thank you so much for your help :).